# Can't set the field separator in AWK, problems with paths with spaces in them

Tags: bash, awk, fs, separator, quoting

I've tried this:

```
echo -e '1 \t 2 \t 3 \t 4' | awk -F"\t" '{print "$3="$3, "$4="$4}'
```

And it works perfectly fine.

However, I've been having problems when I try to do this:

```
aux1=`echo $i | awk -F"\t" '{print $11}'`
```

or this:

```
aux1=`echo $i | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $11}'`
```

Where "i" is the output of "find" and "aux1" is supposed to store a path.

The thing is that if I don't try and change the default field separator, then every path with a space in it is going to be wrong, but if I write it like that, then I just get the "usage" message from awk stored in "aux1", because apparently I'm doing something wrong.

If I write it like this instead (without trying to set the FS) it "works", but the paths with spaces in them are left incomplete:

```
aux1=`echo $i | awk '{print $11}'`
```

Comment: `aux1=\`echo -e $i | awk -F"\t" '{print $11}'\`` - This works for me. Can you give example path you are having issues with?

Comment: /home/pablo/Desktop/test/test\ folder/insideFolder

If I get that path in "i", then I'm just gonna get

/home/pablo/Desktop/test/test\

in aux1

Comment: I still don't see any issue. This gives me correct path `i="field1 \t field2 \t /home/pablo/Desktop/test/test\ folder/insideFolder"; aux1=\`echo -e "$i" | awk -F"\t" '{print $3}'\`; echo $aux1`. Can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: Usage: file [-bchikLlNnprsvz0] [--apple] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type]
            [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
       file -C [-m magicfiles]
       file [--help]

Comment: Apparently it's asking for a file after '{print $11}'. If I add a path to a text file, then it doesn't show that "usage" message, but it doesn't ask for it if I don't use the -F"\t" parameter (which actually works with the text file).

Comment: I must be a little slow, but I don't get it.  If '$i' contains the output of find, which I presume is a path, how would it have 11 fields??  Are you saying that your path names have 10+ tabs in them.  please show the complete find command and a list of possible output.  Also please provide what the 11th field would be in said output?

Comment: find returns much more than just a path, it has file sizes, dates, permissions, etc. separated by tabs and the path is in the 11th field

Comment: 528533    4 drwxrwxr-x   5 pablo    pablo        4096 Jun 18 16:06 /home/pablo/Desktop/test

Comment: that looks like the output of `find . -name test -ls`. If you remove the `-ls`, you'll get just the path, right? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `find . -ls` does not use tabs to separate fields, but spaces. You can check it:

```
find . -ls | od -c
```

So, it's pointless to try anything with tabs as field separators, because there aren't any.

There are only spaces, and there is no way to distinguish between the spaces separating two fields, and the spaces inside a file name.

Since the path starts at field number 11 and extends until the end of the line, a very **ugly workaround** is:

```
echo "$i" | awk '{for (i = 11; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%s ", $i; } printf "\n"}'
```

This prints all the fields starting from 11 until the last field of each line, separated by a space. If a path contains one or more non-consecutive spaces, this solution can correctly reconstruct it . However, if a path contains, for example, two spaces in a row, this solution would erroneously print only one instead of two spaces.

---

**Note:**

In your question you used `echo $i` without quotes, instead of `echo "$i"`. Note that the **quotes are absolutely necessary** here, otherwise all the newlines will be replaced by spaces, and you cannot even distinguish records from fields anymore.

---

If you want a cleaner solution, then better save a different type of data in `i`, e.g. only the paths (one per line):

```
i=$(find .)
```

Then, you can for example extract individual paths by setting the field separator to `\n` and disabling the record separator:

```
echo "$i" | awk -vFS="\n" -vRS="" '{print $3}'
```

This would print the full third path, not matter whether it contains spaces or not.